# "top" vs "docker stats" seems to report different CPU resource utilization figures - why?

Tags: docker

On an Ubuntu 22.04 VM running PostgreSQL as a docker service (on a Docker Swarm node), looking at resource utilization of the service on the VM (`docker stats`) seems to give stats compared to resource utilization reported via `top` on the VM directly.

I understand the that the "CPU %" column in docker stats is, roughly speaking `100% = 1 CPU`. Is that correct? If so, then the output of the `docker stats` command implies that 16 CPUs are roughly being used at 100% capacity (which is what should be the case, i've specified `--cpus 16`)

```
$ docker stats
CONTAINER ID   NAME              CPU %      MEM USAGE / LIMIT   MEM %     NET I/O        BLOCK I/O        PIDS
0d95cd7wef16   postgis_v15....   1595.06%   6.824GiB / 11GiB    62.04%    6GB / 45.6MB   46.7GB / 109GB   42
```

The top command shows 16 CPUs utilized at 65ish % though:

```
$ top
Tasks: 385 total,  32 running, 353 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  : 64.3 us, 35.7 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  : 69.1 us, 30.2 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  : 64.5 us, 35.2 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.3 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  : 66.0 us, 34.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu4  : 63.8 us, 35.9 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu5  : 67.0 us, 31.7 sy,  0.0 ni,  1.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu6  : 65.9 us, 31.8 sy,  0.0 ni,  1.0 id,  1.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu7  : 67.3 us, 32.3 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu8  : 61.0 us, 38.7 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu9  : 66.1 us, 33.9 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu10 : 62.2 us, 35.1 sy,  0.0 ni,  2.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu11 : 59.3 us, 40.1 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu12 : 65.1 us, 34.9 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu13 : 64.7 us, 35.3 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu14 : 61.3 us, 38.7 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu15 : 67.7 us, 32.3 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
GiB Mem :     11.7 total,      0.4 free,      2.4 used,      8.9 buff/cache
GiB Swap:      1.0 total,      1.0 free,      0.0 used.      4.4 avail Mem
```

(Please let me know if my interpretation of either `docker stats` or `top` is incorrect)

What is the cause of the discrepancy in `top` vs `docker stats` resource usage reportin?

Comment: After searching "us vs sy top command", I see that 'us' is time spent processing user-related tasks, and 'sy' is time spent on kernel related tasks. So actually... this is roughly 100% use

Answer (score 0):

After searching "us vs sy top command", I see that 'us' is time spent processing user-related tasks, and 'sy' is time spent on kernel related tasks. So actually... this is roughly 100% use